# Как использовать атрибут data вместо классов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как использовать атрибут data вместо классов в скрипте?

**Вот таблица с классом:**

```
<table class="tg room-1004">
```

**А мне нужно вот так:**

```
<table class="tg" data-room="1004">
```

Знаю, что нужно что-то тут поменять, но что — не понимаю, экспериментировал так и этак:

```
function time_select(room, area, trainer) {
  $("table.room-" + room + " .item").removeClass("select");
  $("table.room-" + room + " .area-" + area).addClass("select");
  $("table.room-" + room + " .it").removeClass("select");
  $("table.room-" + room + " .trainer-" + trainer).addClass("select");
  return false;
}
```

**Код всего примера:**

```
<button class="destination" data-p1="1004" data-p2="0" data-p3="1197">Хатха-йога</button>

<table class="tg room-1004">
  <tr>
    <td class="item area-1011 trainer-1197"><a href="#">Хатха-йога</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
.select {
  outline: 2px solid #D5110D;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}
</style>

<script>
var destination = $('.destination');

destination.click(function() {
   destination.on('click', time_select($(this).data('p1'), $(this).data('p2'), $(this).data('p3')));
});

function time_select(room, area, trainer) {
  $("table.room-" + room + " .item").removeClass("select");
  $("table.room-" + room + " .area-" + area).addClass("select");
  $("table.room-" + room + " .it").removeClass("select");
  $("table.room-" + room + " .trainer-" + trainer).addClass("select");
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то в данном случае это будет `$("table[data-room=" + room + "] .item")` и проще использовать именно класс.... если доп манипуляций с данными не предвидится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$("table[data-room=" + room + "] .item")
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а как со второй строчкой? $("table.room-" + room + " .area-" + area).addClass("select");

Comment: @alex-lenk там все тоже самое. Заменяете всё на `[data-room=" + room + "]` вместо `.room-" + room + "`

Comment: спасибо большое ваш ответ помог решить проблему!